# ScssPhp Assetic filter doesn't work on dev mode

Tags: symfony, assetic, internal-server-error

I'm trying to compile the twitter bootstrap with Assetic and ScssPhp in Symfony.

The following command work well

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Bootstrap are well compiled and work in prod mode.

But in dev mode, all CSS files work excepted `bootstrap.css`. An internal error is given for `bootstrap css`. In the Apache log I have this:

> [Fri Dec 02 14:30:23.578786 2016] [:error] [pid 13015] [client
>   127.0.0.1:59442] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in
>   /home/niga/www/public/messenger/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php
>   on line 65

Symfony log:

> [2016-12-02 14:46:41] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}".
>   {"route":"_assetic_99d6e1c_0","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"99d6e1c","pos":0,"_format":"css","_route":"_assetic_99d6e1c_0"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1/public/messenger-2/web/app_dev.php/css/99d6e1c_bootstrap_1.css","method":"GET"}
>   []